# I need to run a comparison test of mean biomass of species between 2 different locations. Problem - too many zero values for my dependent variable

Tags: anova, t-test, mean, zero-inflation

I need to run a t-test and series of ANOVA tests (through SPSS, excel, or Matlab) to compare the biomass of 20 species (dependent variable) found at 2-4 different locations (independent variable).

The problem I have is that I have many zero values (indicating no record of that species observed on several surveying days) for biomass of individual species, which is bringing the average biomass value incredibly low per species. Is there a formula or stats test that accounts for ''non-observations'? Any advice or recommendations?

Thank you!

Comment: Is it a case of missing data or a measurement of zero?

Comment: It indicates that the species was not observed on that particular survey date, but is a known species of that region.

Comment: My interpretation is that the zeros count and should pull down the average. What makes you think this is incorrect?

Comment: Typical avg. values range between 2-200 gm-2, and I am getting 0- 2 gm-2, with most between 0-0.5 gm-2.  it could imply species collapse for most, but I thought maybe the zeros (non-observations) were skewing my data.

Comment: 1) Are those values calculated after removing the $0$s? I have seen papers published where they do that (and not all of them have explicitly mentioned that they do so). 2) Might you have something interesting going on that causes you not to see the species as often as other groups have seen the species?

Comment: I don't believe they removed the 0s, but you have seen papers who remove the 0s, implying it could be statistical sound to not include them when averaging? 

There is no reason as far as surveying methodology that I would have lower values than previous studies.

Comment: Let's say that 1 species was surveyed 300 times over a 10-year period, and I have 30 biomass values ranging between 0.5- 120 gm-2 and the rest are 0 values.  If I am not accounting for time, and simply looking at the average found at the site, would it be statistical sound to remove 0 values (non-observations)? or should I still account for them?

Comment: If you remove the $0$s, then you are looking at the variable conditioned on the value not being zero. This might be fine; this might be invalid. Do not, however, think that you are looking at the original quantity.

Answer (score 0):

How about trying to predict the number of individuals found instead of the biomass?
You can then look at a useful question: Is it Poisson, or does this species flock together? For a herding species, average biomass isn't a very meaningful figure over any small area.

Once you have a model of number of individuals, you can also investigate individual weight, to get to biomass. Of course, the mean weight might be different in areas where the species is dense.

Comment: Unfortunately, the dataset that I have been given only discloses biomass.